# Why shouldn't I run bundle install as root?

Tags: bundler

I was playing around with bundler and noticed a warning when running `bundle install` with root privileges:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things which interact with each other to make installing most software as root a "bad idea":

- Most programs which create files default to creating them as the user who ran the program.
- Files created by root typically don't give anyone else read/write/execute permissions.

In the case of installing packages as root with Bundler, this means that the scripts in the ruby gem you install would not be accessible to any other users.

Comment: Why these scripts should be accessible to other users ? when we want these to be only accessible to root user which is running Apache and Passenger.

Comment: Well, ideally you shouldn't be running Passenger as root either. Your web server should be run as a non-shell user who only has file permissions for the directories you actually intend to publish. This way the filesystem itself enforces security in the case you get a malicious/stupid user trying to upload or execute code that will harm the environment.